# Add constraints based on view's height iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have several subviews which are laid out based on the size of their super view. And I use auto layout here but the size of the super view is always 0, here is the code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame Count:(NSUInteger)count
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        self.count = count;

        const float circleHeight = self.bounds.size.height * (float)4 / (5 * self.count - 1);
        NSLog(@"selfHeight %f",self.bounds.size.height);        

        for (UIImageView * circle in self.circleViewArray)
        {
            [self addSubview:circle];
        }

        for (int i = 0;i < self.count;i++)
        {
            [self.circleViewArray[i] mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker * make){
                make.width.equalTo(self);
                make.height.equalTo(self).multipliedBy((float)4 / (5 * self.count - 1));
                make.centerX.equalTo(self);
                make.bottom.equalTo(self).with.offset(-i * (circleHeight + stickHeight));
            }];
        }
    }

    return self;

}
```

Note that here I use the third-party Masonry to simplify my code.
When I print the "selfHeight" in the console the output is always 0. How should I handle it?
[image: Just look at the blue circles and omit others]

Comment: Where are you getting the frame to pass in?

Comment: I just pass a CGRectZero to the method cause I auto-layouted it in its super view

Comment: How are your circle views supposed to be arranged? Could you add a screenshot / sketch how it is supposed to look like?

Comment: If `bounds` is `CGRectZero`, then I'd suggest checking what you passed for the `frame` and make sure that wasn't `CGRectZero`, too. You'd see that if you grabbed `frame` during the view controller's `viewDidLoad` or something like that.

Comment: Actually I pass a frame to the parent view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your offsets are never going to work because they're calculated against zero and never updated. You need to make the constraints relative somehow, or you need to remove and update the constraints each time the frame changes (the layout needs to be updated).

Making the constraints relative is better, which in your case you should look at linking the views together so the spacing between yhen is set and the heights resize to fit the full available height.

Pseudocode:

```
UIView *previousView = nil;

for (view in views) {

    view.leading = super.leading;
    view.trailing = super.trailing;

    if (previousView) {
        view.top = previousView.bottom;
        view.height = previousView.height; // equal relation, not static height
    } else {
        view.top = super.top;
    }

    previousView = view;
}

previousView.bottom = super.bottom;
```

Comment: I know they're calculated against zero but I was just wondering why the height is zero.

Comment: Width and height of self are both zero when you make the calculation.

Comment: So how can I use the width and height of self here?

Comment: Don't. Pin the views to the edges and each other and allow the width and height to be determined by the layout engine

Comment: I don't quite understand. Could you please show me the code that setup the constraint?

Comment: Added pseudocode so you can see how to link the views together conceptually and ensure the height is distributed across them

Comment: Ok so I still can't use the height of self here. But inspired by your approach I came up with a trick to solve this problem, thanks.